# A counterexample for an integral inequality

Tags: integration

I'm looking for functions $f,g \in L^1$ such that $f < g$ and $\int f = \int g$.

I know that $f \le g \Rightarrow \int f \le \int g$, but I suppose the implication with the strict inequality doesn't hold (am I correct?).

Comment: $f<g$ still implies $\int f\leq\int g$. But I do suspect we can't have equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show that if $f\geq 0$ satisfies $\int f= 0$, then $f$ vanishes almost everywhere. Thus, there is no $f,g\in L^1$ with $f\leq g$ such that
$
f< g
$ on a set of positive measure and $\int f=\int g$.

Comment: I was wondering if this is true also for Riemann's integral. I mean if f is bounded (not necessarily continuous) on [a,b] is it true that f > 0 ⇒ ∫f > 0?

Comment: Yes. You can see it by noting that every Riemann integrable function is Lebesgue integrable.